# Suddenly cannot connect to server with Public IP

Tags: networking, ip, firewall, webserver, teamspeak

Everything worked fine until last night. I was connecting to the server perfectly fine, went to bed and then suddenly I cannot anymore. Connecting to the TeamSpeak 3 server it's running using the local network IP address works perfectly fine but using the public IP address (which is port forwarded correctly, as I stated it worked yesterday) no longer works with no explanation. The router didn't change, the server box hasn't changed, the IP hasn't changed. Everything is perfectly identical as it was last night.

I've tried -

- Restarting the router
- Restarting the server box
- Trying to connect from different networks and computers
- Ping from external websites
- Reinstalling the server software itself
- Firewall disabled
- Full TCP/UDP Inbound and Outbound rules

Comment: Speak to your ISP - the only thing you haven't tried yet.

Comment: @DavidPostill Is there any other problem? I've got Time Warner Cable and last thing I wanna do is get on the phone with those idiots. Nothing changed between last night and today, less than 6 hours of time difference and it suddenly stopped.

Comment: You will have to co fact your isp

Comment: `Nothing changed between last night and today` .... so, why are you posting this question ???           ..................  `less than 6 hours of time difference and it suddenly stopped` ... do you think that things need more time to fail?